# system cannot get java compiler please use jdk intead of jre

Tags: java, google-app-engine

When trying to deploy my application to the Google App Engine server I get the following error:

`Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.`

All solutions I've seen for this involve editing an eclipse configuration file, but I'm not using eclipse. I'm executing **appcfg.cmd** from the dos prompt.

I have a jdk installed and my **JAVA_HOME** is pointing to it: 
**c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few points:

- Could you check if the JAVA_HOME\bin folder is in the PATH environment variable. If not put that and make sure that it is pointing to the correct version.
- Also check java -version on your machine after setting it.

Comment: after doing as you suggested it is giving an error
" 'java' is not reconized as the internal or external command,
operable program or batch file"

Comment: The error means that there is a problem with your PATH variable. Though you might have put that, there is an issue and it is not getting recognized, hence even the java.exe is not being found on the PATH. Please check the same. Do the following, echo out the PATH value on the terminal or command prompt and see what is being printed. It should contain the directory that has your java*.exe files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the bin folder as the sub-directory please give it a try

```
c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin
```